# How to show messages followed by the same id?

Tags: php, mysql

People, I need to list the chat messages one below the other, I tried to do this script but the result is different.

```
<?php
openConnection();
$stmt2 = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT texto, who FROM system_chat WHERE userid=? ORDER by id ASC");
$stmt2->bind_param("i", $_SESSION["userid"]);
$stmt2->execute();
$stmt2->store_result();
if($stmt2->num_rows >= 1) {
    $stmt2->bind_result($texto, $who);
    while($stmt2->fetch()) {
        if($who == "Admin") {
            echo "
                <div class='list-group-item media'>
                    <div class='pull-left'>
                        <img class='avatar-img' src='".PATH_THEME."/demo/img/profile-pics/1.jpg' alt=''>
                    </div>
                    <div class='media-body'>
                        <div>
                            <div class='messages__item'>
                                {$texto}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            ";
        } else if($who == "User") {
            echo "
                <div class='list-group-item media'>
                    <div class='pull-right'>
                        <img class='avatar-img' src='".PATH_THEME."/demo/img/profile-pics/8.jpg' alt=''> 

                    </div>
                    <div class='media-body'>
                        <div>
                            <div class='messages__item'>
                                {$texto}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <small class='ms-date'><i class='zmdi zmdi-time'></i> 20/02/2015 at 09:30</small>
                    </div>
                </div>
            ";
        }
    }
}
$stmt2->close();
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

The result of the code above was what is in the image below
[image]

But what I need is this way that is in the image below

[image]

I made this without mysql and php

Comment: This seems like more of a CSS issue. What are the styles of `.pull-left` and `.pull-right`?

Comment: use in your query `ORDER by texto` and not by `id`